# how to change color of dropdown underline

Tags: flutter, colors, dropdown, underline

in my code **`Container(height: 1, color: UtilColors.grey),`** not giving expeceted output

```
Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 52, right: 48),
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                isExpanded: true,
                //Container(height: 1, color: UtilColors.grey),
                value: _selectedUser,
                items: _userTypes.map((String value) {
                  return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: value, child: new Text(value));
                }).toList(),
               /* decoration: InputDecoration(contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15), suffixIcon: IconButton(onPressed: () {
                 // _userTypes.map((String value){return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: value, child: new Text(value));}).toList();
                   }, icon: Icon(null),)),*/
                icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                hint: Text(UtilString.userType),
                onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _selectedUser = value),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

finally got the solution with DropdownButton -

underline: Container( height: 2,
color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,),

this will change dropdown underline color.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DropdownButtonFormField(


                                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                             focusedBorder: new UnderlineInputBorder(
                                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: Colors.black
                                              ),),


                                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color:  Color(0xff22a39f), width: 2),

                                                ),
                                             ),
                                            // iconEnabledColor:  Color(0xff22a39f),


                                            hint: Text("اختر صنف"),

                                            value:selectedValueInDropDpownM ,
                                            items: choosenResala?.ctegoriesDetails.map(( value) {
                                              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(


                                                value: value.catName,
                                                child: Text(value.catName,style: TextStyle( fontSize:
                                                screenWidth * 0.013,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                    FontWeight.w400,color: Colors.black ),),
                                              );
                                            }).toList(),
                                            onChanged: ( newVal) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                selectedValueInDropDpownM=newVal as String?;
                                              });


                                            },
                                          )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).